# Constraint check if row and other row not null on same time

Tags: oracle

I have a school 'project' to work on, which has some tables and one table needs to have a constraint which is not working out for me.

There are some tables like QUESTION, ANSWER and REACTION.
A reaction belongs with or a question or a answer but not both on the same time.
There by I have 2 rows:

```
  question_id         NUMBER,
  answer_id           NUMBER,
```

Both not null because the cant by null, but not on the same time.

I already made a constraint but isn't working..

```
  /* CHECK if reaction belongs to an question or a answer             NOT WORKING YET*/
CONSTRAINT CHECK_question_or_answer CHECK((answer_id != NULL AND question_id = NULL) OR (answer_id = NULL OR question_id != NULL))
```

Already tested the constraint and I can insert a value without a question_id or answer_id.
I hope it's a bit clear, if not, I am happy yo try explain myself better.
(still newby on SQL)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: "Already tested the constraint and I can insert a value without a question_id or answer_id." So what exactly is the usecase that isn't working properly for you?

Comment: **`IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`**. Comparison operator with `NULL` always produce `NULL`

Comment: @LuciaPasarin sorry, auto-generatad tag by stackoverflow (usering oracle)

Comment: @Mureinik not clear what you are trying to say

Comment: @lad2025 still newby but not sure how your answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT CHECK_question_or_answer CHECK((answer_id != NULL AND profile_id = NULL) OR (answer_id = NULL OR profile_id != NULL))
```

Is always **FALSE**.

You need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` like:

```
CONSTRAINT CHECK_question_or_answer CHECK((answer_id IS NOT NULL AND profile_id IS NULL) OR (answer_id IS NULL OR profile_id IS NOT NULL))
```

This is because comparison operators `!= , = , > , <,` combined with `NULL` produce `NULL` and are treated as false.

Demo:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dual
WHERE 1 IS NOT NULL;

SELECT 1
FROM dual
WHERE 1 != NULL;
```

From [doc](http://psoug.org/definition/NULL.htm):

> NULL values represent missing or unknown data. NULL values are used as
>   placeholders or as the default entry in columns to indicate that no
>   actual data is present. The NULL is untyped in SQL, meaning that it is
>   not an integer, a character, or any other specific data type.
>
> Note that NULL is not the same as an empty data string or the
>   numerical value '0'. While NULL indicates the absence of a value, the
>   empty string and numerical zero both represent actual values.
>
> While a NULL value can be assigned, it can not be equated with
>   anything, including itself.
>
> **Because NULL does not represent or equate to a data type, you cannot
>   test for NULL values with any comparison operators, such as =, <, or
>   <>.**
>
> **The IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators are used to test for NULL
>   values.**

Comment: @JimVercoelen See my updated answer, hope this is now clear

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around. Put the id of the main table in the others like that

```
question table
--------------
id
text
...


answers table
-------------
id
question_id
text
...


reactions table
---------------
id
question_id
text
...
```

And `question_id` is never null. Then you can use a `left join` to get the results from both tables - one of them will have no results.

```
select *
from questions q
left join answers a on a.question_id = q.id
left join reactions r on r.question_id = q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

While @lad2025s answer is good for two columns, if you wanted to extend the method to more than two it can get a bit cumbersome.

A flexible alternative is:

```
check ((case when answer_id   is null then 0 else 1 end +
        case when question_id is null then 0 else 1 end ) = 1)
```

It extends well to checking for a particular count of null (or non-null) values for an arbitrary number of columns.

For example, if you had column_1, column_2, column3, and column_4, and wanted *at least 1* of them to be non-null, then:

```
check ((case when column_1 is null then 0 else 1 end +
        case when column_2 is null then 0 else 1 end +
        case when column_3 is null then 0 else 1 end +
        case when column_4 is null then 0 else 1 end ) >= 1)
```